# How should I setup PhpStorm in order to debug microservices with Docker?

Tags: php, docker, phpstorm, xdebug, xdebug-3

Let's say I have two microservices running in two different Docker containers: `ServiceA` and `ServiceB`. `ServiceA` makes an HTTP request to `ServiceB` and this one sends a response back. I would like to be able if it is possible, to start my debugging session in `ServiceA` (instance of PhpStorm) and switch it to `ServiceB` (instance of PhpStorm) once the call is sent and then get back to `ServiceA`. To be clear, I will have two PhpStorm windows opened: one for `ServiceA` and one for `ServiceB`.

Here are some notes from my current configuration:

- ServiceA: PHP 7.4.x, Xdebug 3.0.4
- ServiceB: PHP 7.2.x, Xdebug 3.0.4

The Xdebug settings are the same for `ServiceA` and `ServiceB`:

```
zend_extension=xdebug.so
xdebug.mode=debug
xdebug.discover_client_host=true
```

As per the `File | Settings | PHP | Debug` configuration in PhpStorm they look as follow and are the same for `ServiceA` and `ServiceB`:

[image]

Since `ServiceB` should be Listening for Incoming connection this is how that little green bug toolbar looks like:

[image]

What issues I am having?

- I am able to start the debugging session in `ServiceA` but it never switches to `ServiceB`, the session finishes correctly though.
- The following "warning" spam my `stdout` logs for `ServiceB`:

> Xdebug: [Step Debug] Could not connect to debugging client. Tried: 172.18.0.9:9003 (from REMOTE_ADDR HTTP header), localhost:9003 (fallback through xdebug.client_host/xdebug.client_port)

What I could be possibly missing here?

> Note: if more information is needed just ask me and I will add it

Comment: "xdebug.discover_client_host=true" that's very likely not going to do what you want. It uses HTTP headers to find out the IP address of where the HTTP request came from, and make Xdebug (try to) connect to an IDE on that machine. I bet `172.18.0.9:9003` does not have your IDE listening on it.

Answer (score 0):

The option `xdebug.start_with_request = yes` tells Xdebug to try to debug every single request/script. If Xdebug fails to connect to the debug client (it takes values from `xdebug.client_host` and `xdebug.client_port`) then it notifies you about that.

Normally such a messages will be written to the standard PHP's error log. Looks like you don't have it configured at all in your php.ini (as this is how it comes by default), therefore PHP sends it to your standard output instead.

If you want to prevent it from appearing on you terminal output you have to point the PHP error_log to a valid location.

Example of how I solved it in my case:

1- Edit your ini file:

`sudo vi /etc/php/7.4/cli/php.ini`

2- And add this line:

`error_log = /var/www/log/php_error.log`

NOTE: Change the previous routes to any valid directory you want.

3- Try again and the warning should disappear and now goes to the log file.